# How to get TimeZone from Temporal?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, temporal

```
interface SomeDataClass {
  TemporalAccessor getSomeTime();
}

//somewhere in the impl...
public TemporalAccessor getSomeTime() {
  return OffsetDateTime.from(dateTimeFormatter.parse(someDateInstring));
}
```

Does anyone know how to get timezone data from this `TemporalAccessor` interface?

Comment: I strongly advise against the use of `Temporal` (or `TemporalAccessor`) because code like `ZoneOffset.from(acc)` can throw a `DateTimeException` (for example if you have a concrete `LocalDateTime`-object). It is not type-safe at all. Better always work with final concrete types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the `ZoneOffset` or `ZoneId`, you can create it from the `TemporalAccessor`:

```
TemporalAccessor acc = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(ZoneOffset.from(acc));
System.out.println(ZoneId.from(acc));
```

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for, thank you very much!